# How to add class to tr on dataTable if data has ID and then save it as sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I'm using dataTables for fetching the data on the front-end. For this scenario, I'll just add a dummy datatable for this. My goal is to highlight/addClass to the selected row and save it to the `sessionStorage` so that when user refreshes the page it will still be highlighted.

I want to add a class `selected` only to the selected row that has a `shipment_id` on it and save it to `sessionStorage`. If `shipment_id` is empty then don't highlight the row or save it to session.

I have a JSFiddle here as an example for the scenario. But the function that I've tried is only highlighting the specific row when clicked and ignoring the `shipment_id` data. Is there any way to modify the functions or the code to only `addClass()` and save to `sessionStorage` if `shipment_id` has value?

Link here for
**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/laurence1105/vykqx4z7/8/)**

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just add the check if the shipment ID value is present to call the highlight and session store function?

```
...
rowData = table.row(this).data()[1]; // get data of shipment ID
if (rowData) {
    table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    persistSelection( table.row(this).index(), $(this).hasClass('selected'));
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but its storing the index of the `tr` on the session.  Its not storing the `shipment_id`.

Comment: Then just pass the shipment ID to the function and store it in the store like here https://jsfiddle.net/1jq4snkh/1/ or am I missing something?

Comment: this one is awesome.. this one will save it to session and also add the class `.selected`. Hmm but when I click on previous/next or the numbering the class selected is still there. I'm guessing need to call the `fnRowCallback` function so that when table is refreshed the added class will not be there? Any ideas?

Comment: When you switch to the next page the table is not being refreshed, that is why the selection is still there when you switch back to page 1. Do you want to reset the selection and store when you go to page 2 or what?

Comment: Yeah..

basically like this.

1. Click on specific row 
2. store the shipment ID and add class to `tr` of that specific row  
3. Go to page 2 or other pages > don't highlight any row.

But the behavior for the code is:

(E.G.)
1. Click on 3rd row with the shipmentID 
2. shipmentID stored to the session and then add class to `tr` 3rd row 
3. Go to next page or other page, although the shipmentID session is stored its still highlighting all the 3rd rows of each the pages.

In the fiddle, the behavior is okay but when fetching data on serverside it highlights the rows of each page.

Comment: I'm not really sure what could be the reason for that behaviour as I cannot see the data when it is fetched from the server. Are you sure that every `tr` has a unique class so that the selector does not add the highlight class to each row on every page?